# Image won't resize or adjust with CSS and HTML code

Tags: html, css, image

so I've been trying a lot of codes to make this work and nothing seems to be working in my end for my Squarespace website.

I'm not a web designer nor developer but I'm also trying to learn, this "easy" kind of code looks very simple but am having a hard time. Even if I replace the image, it still stays the same size.

Please see the code here:

CSS:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
```

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/09/26/14/04/etretat-4506072_1280.jpg" alt="landing page" width="1500" height="528">
  <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Would be glad to hear yall thoughts. thank you so much, it's so frustrating for me right now.

Comment: What is your exact error? What is your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the `max-width` property which the container has.
Just remove it if you don't want the images to be at the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you. I fixed your code in HTML.
For image resizing, you should use 'px'.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.container img {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
}
</style>
<h1>Html:</h1>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/09/26/14/04/etretat-4506072_1280.jpg" alt="landing page" width="1500" height="528">
  <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```